Problems in compiling a Fortran file coming from a GitHub repo in VSCode with cmake and gfortran
I downloaded a GitHub repo. Its files are in the .f90 format.
I downloaded cmake and gfortran in order to compile and run the files.
According to what the repo says, i write on the terminal as follows:
mkdir build
cd build
cmake ..
make

The first two lines give the expected output. The third one fails. This is the error message:
PS C:\Users\angel\neural-fortran\build> cmake ..
-- Selecting Windows SDK version 10.0.22621.0 to target Windows 10.0.22631.
-- The Fortran compiler identification is unknown
-- Detecting Fortran compiler ABI info
CMake Error: Generator: execution of make failed. Make command was: devenv.com CMAKE_TRY_COMPILE.sln /build Debug /project cmTC_65ff7
-- Detecting Fortran compiler ABI info - failed
-- Check for working Fortran compiler: C:\msys64\ucrt64\bin\gfortran.exe
CMake Error: Generator: execution of make failed. Make command was: devenv.com CMAKE_TRY_COMPILE.sln /build Debug /project cmTC_2eb8a
-- Check for working Fortran compiler: C:\msys64\ucrt64\bin\gfortran.exe - broken
CMake Error at C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.31/Modules/CMakeTestFortranCompiler.cmake:59 (message):
  The Fortran compiler

    "C:\msys64\ucrt64\bin\gfortran.exe"

  is not able to compile a simple test program.

  It fails with the following output:

    Change Dir: 'C:/Users/angel/neural-fortran/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeScratch/TryCompile-3ec0fh'

    Run Build Command(s): devenv.com CMAKE_TRY_COMPILE.sln /build Debug /project cmTC_2eb8a
    no such file or directory
    Generator: execution of make failed. Make command was: devenv.com CMAKE_TRY_COMPILE.sln /build Debug /project cmTC_2eb8a




  CMake will not be able to correctly generate this project.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:9 (project)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!

To note that both gfortran and cmake are part of the path.
I don't know how to proceed in order to effectively execute cmake ..

Where does your gfortran installation come from? Have you tested it? Please try to compile some simple Hello world program with your gfortran and tell us whether it works or not. For more details of what cmake tried see the log file.
